# In big and reputed companies, does a manager have the power to arbitrarily fire a reportee or does some process need to be followed?

Tags: manager

He may want to do this for ego reasons or because he doesn't like you rather than because of performance.
Is there any mechanism for the reportee to protect himself?
EDIT: THe country is India. There are no laws to protect tech employees and union is also not there.

Comment: This is highly dependent on country/state/union/company rules regarding dismissal procedures.  You're going to have to expand your question in order to give more context here.

Comment: Depends on local laws and company policy, so too broad a question. You need to either talk to HR and/or a lawyer

Comment: Best mechanism is not to peeve the manager until they want to fire you.

Answer (score 2):

In most companies, a manager doesn't have the power to just fire anyone. In the USA, *the company* may have the power, but the manager usually doesn't. He can go to HR and tell them why he wants someone fired. It is very unlikely that HR will just follow that request, because firing good employees because the manager doesn't like them is not good for business. Putting that request to HR will actually not look good for the manager. In Europe, you need a good reason to fire anyone. "The manager didn't like him" is *not* a good reason.

In "big and reputed companies", at least the one that I worked at, any retaliation against employees who complain for legitimate reasons is very discouraged. The manager trying this would get himself into more trouble than the employee.

In reality, this should never happens. If it happened, then it looks like you don't have a very good manager, so get rid.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on jurisdiction (location) and on individual company policies.

Some locations have "at will" employment, where staff can be dismissed with no reason given. Others will have employee protection legislation and/or the option to report the incident to an industrial tribunal.

If you're in a jurisdiction where legislation is in force, individual company policy will have more to do with their conscientiousness than their size. In such locations (I'm thinking mainly of Western Europe), even small companies will have a documented disciplinary policy. Not following this policy could be grounds for former employees to claim unfair dismissal.

There will be certain types of incident that will be classified as misconduct and could trigger immediate dismissal (violence, theft, dishonesty, sexual activity and others). In a conscientious company, the things that will be defined as misconduct (or, subject to jurisdiction, as "gross misconduct") will be specifically defined in the company policy.

The short answer is that reputed companies - irrespective of size - will have obtained that reputation by having conscientious policies. What a dismissed employee can do will be dependent on the legislation in force and the availability of industrial tribunals. For employees who believe they have been unfairly dismissed, the best first step would be to consult with a competent legal professional.

Comment: Remember: The manager is not the company. The question was about the manager.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I thought that after reading your answer, but by then there was already an answer that said it...

Answer (score 0):

> In big and reputed companies, does a manager have the power to arbitrarily fire a reportee or does some process need to be followed?

Not all "Big companies" are alike. When a manager wants someone fired, then there are several ways how different companies handle this:

- There is a separate instance which makes hire-and-fire decisions. Concerns of the manager are noted, but the decision is made on objectively measurable criteria.
- There is a separate instance which makes hire-and-fire decisions. They claim to make objective decisions, but smart managers know how to game the system. They can get anyone fired if they know what they need to tell them.
- There is a separate instance which makes hire-and-fire decisions, but it bases its decisions mostly on the opinon of the direct manager. If a manager wants someone fired, they will look if there is a way to make that happen.
- Managers do have permission to fire reports directly.

We can not tell you what kind of company you are working for. You need to find out on your own.

> Is there any mechanism for the reportee to protect himself?

Working with a manager who does not like you is something you really want to avoid in the long term. It stunts your career and it is bad for your mental health.

When you realize that you and your direct manager do not get along with each other, then the best option for both sides would be to switch departments. See if there is an internal job offering in the company you could apply to. If you are well connected to other managers, you could also ask around if anyone currently thinks about creating a new position you could apply to.

But such an opportunity does not always arise.

If you really insist on staying on a workplace with a manager who dislikes you, then it is important for you to provide counter-testimony whenever your manager acts against you.

- If you feel that your manager behaves abusive towards you, document it.
- If you receive a written citation about something you did or did not do, always provide a counter-statement.